# sublist of a p:datatable not working in p:columns

Tags: jsf, datatable, nested-lists

I am using `p:datatable`. The value inside `p:columns` is a sublist of `p:datatable`. But the list inside `p:column` is not displaying in the UI.

```
<p:dataTable id="examMarksVie" var="internal" editable="true"
    rowIndexVar="rowindex" rowKey="#{internal.internalMarkId}"
    style="width:90%;margin-left:70px;margin-top:5%"
    value="#{exam.internalMarkList}">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{exam.doSaveInternalMark}"
        update="examMarksVie" />
    <p:column
        headerText="#{message['label.studentManagement.transferCertificate.studentName']}">
        <h:outputText
            value="#{internal.studentDetails.studentApplicationID.firstName} #{internal.studentDetails.studentApplicationID.middleName} #{internal.studentDetails.studentApplicationID.lastName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:columns
        value="#{exam.internalMarkList.interALlocMarkList}"
        var="id" columnIndexVar="index"
        headerText="#{id.internalAllocId.titleName} out of #{id.internalAllocId.markDetail}">
        <p:inputText value="#{id.allocMark}" />
    </p:columns>
```

Comment: When i am taking only the first index like below its working.But i need the entire list as different students may have different set of marks. How to achieve this?                                                                                                  <p:columns
        value="#{exam.internalMarkList.get(0).interALlocMarkList}"     @BalusC

Comment: To find the answer, read the Answer, not the Question.

Comment: This is my modified code.now the header is not working.whats problem in my code.                                                                                            <p:column headerText="#{internal[0].allocMark}">
         <ui:repeat value="#{internal.interALlocMarkList}" var="id">
          <p:column>
                  <p:inputText value=" #{id.allocMark}"></p:inputText> 
          </p:column>
         </ui:repeat>
        </p:column>

Answer (score 0):

This impossible to accomplish with JSF using your code. 
Only way to do this is to create your own custom component that contains list (whole datatable). Then insert your CC tag in your existing table (in some p:column), and it will work.

Comment: No one to help to resolve my issue?